# No funciona el setOnItemClickListener de mi listView

Tags: android

Quiero hacer que al seleccionar un item de `SeleccionClienteActivity` se vaya a `RegistroPedidoActivity`, capturando el dato telefono, el metodo `setOnItemClickListener` no funciona, ni siquiera lleva a la siguiente actividad.

No se donde esta el problema.

Este es mi codigo:

```
public class SeleccionClienteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listaCliente;
private List<Cliente> clientes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seleccion_cliente);

    listaCliente = findViewById(R.id.lvClienteList);


    ClienteService clienteService = APICliente.getClient().create(ClienteService.class);

    listaCliente.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            ArrayList<Cliente> milistaCliente = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(milistaCliente);
                    JSONObject objeto = array.getJSONObject(position);
                    int telefonoCli = objeto.getInt("telef_cli");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(SeleccionClienteActivity.this, RegistroPedidoActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("telefonoCli",telefonoCli);
                    startActivity(intent);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    Call call = clienteService.findAll();
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            clientes = (List<Cliente>) response.body();
            listaCliente.setAdapter(new 
            ClienteListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), clientes));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Falló", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias.

Comment: No creo que no funcione,  es un error el cual impide se realice el intent ¿revisaste el LogCat?

Comment: y porque no haces el click dentro del adaptador que llena la lista?, muestra el codigo del adaptador a ver

Answer (score 0):

**1ra posible solución:**
Intenta quitando el focus de todos los elementos con:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Y esto:

```
 listaCliente.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

**2da posible solución:**

Estas usando el método incorrecto para escuchar el evento click.

En vez de:

```
listaCliente.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
```

Usa:

```
 listaCliente.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
```

Comment: El correcto en realidad es new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()   , lo que sucede es que esta teniendo un error dentro del método onItemClick().

Comment: Gracias, pues debería agregarlos si les aparecen

Comment: Así es Denifer, por eso es importante que agregue la información necesaria, el uso del LogCat es esencial cuando se desarrolla en android, puede ser la diferencia entre unos segundos y un día tratando de determinar el problema :-( esperemos actualice su pregunta con más información.